# Qu'est-ce que cette phrase veut dire "dimanche de tiré"?

Tags: sens

> J'ai pensé que c'était toujours un dimanche de tiré, que maman était
>   maintenant enterrée, que j'allais reprendre mon travail et que, somme
>   toute, il n'y avait rien de changé.

Il existe dans toute les versions de L'Étranger mais je ne peux pas le trouver dans d'autres contextes.

Comment: qui avait passé...tirer=passer une période plutôt longue et ardue

Comment: One more Sunday I had got through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est un dimanche de passé, de terminé.

D'après le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer#Verbe) (définition 38.), on peut l'utiliser pour une durée dans le sens de "Terminer".

Définition du [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirer) (I. D. 3.):

> Passer une période considérée comme longue en raison de son caractère pénible; en particulier, passer un temps de service ou de condamnation.

(D'ailleurs une des citations du cnrtl est justement la phrase de ta question ^^)

Answer (score 2):

I think the most accurate, in American English, would be "I thought it was at least a Sunday slogged through..".  Something long, hard, tedious has been survived.